# cloudformation output section validation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, validation, templates, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I'm creating an instance with Elastic IP and the security group.Everything works fine until I add the outputs section.
I'm getting invalid templateBody error after adding the outputs section to the existing template.
The template works fine without the Outputs section.
Below is the relevant code:

```
    "Resources": {
        "InstanceProfile" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
            "Properties" : {
              "Path" : "/",
              "Roles" : ["TEST_Role"]
            }
          },
        "Instance": {
            "Properties": {
                "IamInstanceProfile" : {"Ref" : "InstanceProfile"},
                "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                    {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                        "Ebs": {
                            "VolumeSize": {
                                "Ref": "EBSVolumeSize"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "ImageId": {
                    "Ref": "AMI"
                },
                "InstanceType": {
                    "Ref": "InstanceType"
                },
                "KeyName": {
                    "Ref": "KeyName"
                },
                "SecurityGroupIds": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "SecurityGroup"
                    }
                ],
                "SubnetId": {
                    "Ref": "Subnet"
                }
            },
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance"
            },
        "EIPAddress": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP"
        },
        "IPAssoc": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation",
            "Properties": {
                "InstanceId": {
                    "Ref": "Instance"
                },
                "EIP": {
                    "Ref": "EIPAddress"
                }
            }
        },
    },
    "Outputs" : {
        "PublicIP": {
            "Value": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "Instance", "PublicIp"]},
            "Description": "Public IP of the machine"
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that you have **extra comma**:

```
        }, # <---- here
    },
    "Outputs" : {
        "PublicIP": {
            "Value": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "Instance", "PublicIp"]},
            "Description": "Public IP of the machine"
        }
    }
```

Also, if your **instance is not public**, the template will **fail**, because private instances don't have `PublicIp`, thus you can't output it.

Update on the full template (tested in `us-east-1` and default VPC):

[image]

Comment: Actully the comma(,) is not the problem. I have"SecurityGroup" defined after that. forgot to remove it

Comment: @VilasD. I see. I will check again.

Comment: @VilasD. Your output section is fine. I redeployed your template (after filling out the blanks). There are no issues. Off course if your instance is not public, it will fail, as I wrote. If you still have errors after ensuring that the instance is public, the error must be due to sections of code you are not showing.

Comment: Okay, so at least I should get the PrivateIp instead then. this also does not work. I tried with PrivateDnsName, PrivateIp, PublicDnsName. But still, it says invalid template body

Comment: @VilasD. I run your template  in `us-east-1` and only changed AMI for that region and role to one which I have. The `outputs` works. See screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218794/discussion-between-vilas-d-and-marcin).

Comment: @VilasD. I wonder if there was any luck with the template?